# Google Cloud SQL - How to create window authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a requirement to migrate existing on-prem SQL Server to Google cloud sql and along with this i also wanted to migrate existing jobs(internally executes ssis package) and this jobs are running with windows authentication account.

Is there any way that we can create same windows authentication on cloud sql instance

Comment: To clarify, do you mean migrating the existing windows authentication accounts to Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Basically i want to connect Cloudsql using Window authentication account. is it possible to connect?